# Pass value to another page

Tags: php

test1.php

```
<?php
//dbconnection

$q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = 1";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

echo $row['user_name'].'<a href="test2.php" target="_blank">more..</a>';
?>
```

I want to pass username to test2.php without form. How do I pass the username into the hidden field in test1.php and show the username into the test2.php?

Comment: U can use session, cookie as well. But what have you tried so far?

Comment: As sergio said about session, cookie and what about simply using `GET`

Answer (score 3):

You could store the values in a session, and pull it out on your `test2.php` page, using the `$_SESSION` global.

In `test1.php`, something like this

```
<?php
session_start(); // This has to be the first thing called in PHP
// Connection and query goes here
$_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
?>
```

And in `test2.php`

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['user_name'] ." was sent from test1.php";
// unset($_SESSION['user_name']); 
// This line above removes the session-variable, and it has to be set again if you want to use it further. 
?>
```

Note that `session_start();` has to be called on all pages trying to access the `$_SESSION` globals, and that it has to be the first thing called in your PHP script. Sessions can be globally accessed, and not limited to one page.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways of doing it

you can do `start_session();` and then

do

```
 $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];
```

and on test2.php you can simply do (assuming you have started session there with `start_session();`)

```
echo  $_SESSION['user_name'];
```

You can also do

```
echo $row['user_name'].'<a href="test2.php?user_name='.$row['user_name'].'" target="_blank">more..</a>';
```

And on test2.php you can do

```
echo $_GET['user_name'];
```